# is there a way to compare existing docker image with latest source (Git) and build it only when there is any code change?

Tags: git, docker

I have a gradle task which creates a docker image using the product code in Git. When the task is run docker image is created and pushed to repository/hub. But I would like to have a check where I do it only when there is a code change compared with last/latest docker image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to wrap your `docker build` in a shell script.
This script will build the image with a label whose value is the commit hash.
The script will also check the value of this label for the current image and will compare it with the current commit hash before building.

Answer (score 0):

Just run `docker build` every time.  If nothing has changed, the Docker caching machinery should notice this and skip over every single step of the Dockerfile reusing the cached layer, and it is extremely quick.  (The largest time cost is if you have a large build tree that you're sending to Docker to be built.)